# How to show the relationships of reddit comments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested

In my react app, I have this api which represents some posts from reddit, including their comments.

API:

> https://aud-tech-challenge.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/challenge.json

I need to show the comments and their relations, so i have to show how they are nested.

But the comments is just an array, and when they have children they have a property called 'parent_id'

But i cant think of a way to render the comments as in reddit... nested or with sub comments.

I am trying to map over the array, and then do something... but i dont know what to do, so that i get them nested as they should.

Any ideas?

this is all I have at the moment:

```
          {post.comments.map((post, i) => {
            return (
              <div key={i}>{post.body}</div>
            )
          })}
```

Example comment object:

```
  {
    "created_utc": 1570666050,
    "subreddit_name_prefixed": "r/news",
    "subreddit": "news",
    "depth": 3,
    "permalink": "/r/news/comments/dfn3yi/blizzard_employees_staged_a_walkout_after_the/f351gzq/",
    "body_html": "&lt;div class=\"md\"&gt;&lt;p&gt;I just tested this. It allows you to go through the whole process including SMS verification then it gives you a big red DENIED message.&lt;/p&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;",
    "downs": 0,
    "body": "I just tested this. It allows you to go through the whole process including SMS verification then it gives you a big red DENIED message.",
    "author": "shfiven",
    "id": "t1_f351gzq",
    "ups": 5225,
    "parent_id": "t1_f34z90b"
  },`
```

Comment: You could create a Comment component and use a bunch of ```filter``` calls to pass children whose ```parent_id``` match their ```id```, but it would be very expensive on a large dataset. Maybe there's a better way, but this would probably be best handled by a database which could filter and aggregate the data on the back end into a friendlier format.

Comment: Is there a specific stack you're meant to use for this challenge, e.g. AWS services?

Comment: could you please explain a bit more what you mean i think something like that could work...@RutherfordWonkington it would be great help.

Comment: Sorry posted an answer for the wrong question (too many tabs!). Looking at the data again, it appears the comments provide you a ```depth``` property which tells you ahead of time if it has children, so you may be able to make the filtering process more efficient.

Comment: yeh @RutherfordWonkington but i cant wrap my head around how I would make it... how to get those nested relationships... if you could give me a little guideline it would mean a lot... im a bit desperate. thanks.